# Multiple buttons don't fire clicks event. 5.1.2 memory leak?

Tags: ios, events, click, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

With 5.1.2 my buttons generated by iteration don't works. 
Copy my code and try it with iPad simulator with 5.1.1 and 5.1.2. 
You will see the differences. With 5.1.2, in better case fire first and second buttons.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var data = [];

for(var i=1; i<=6; i++){

    var view = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : 320,
        top : 10,
        bottom : 0
    });



    var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        bottom : 10,
        left : 10,
        right : 10,
        height : 40,
        color : '#fff',
        backgroundColor : 'red',
        title : "click",
        ids: i
    });


    view.add(button);


    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('button: ' + e.source.ids);
    });


    data.push(view);

}

var scroll_view = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    showPagingControl : true,
    top : 130,
    views: data,
    layout: 'horizontal'
});



win.add(scroll_view);
```

Comment: What is the content of the `data` array in 5.1.1 and 5.1.2? Are they the same?

Comment: You can see in the code, data is array of views for scrollableView. I see the same result with the two sdk. Differences are in the click listener that doesn't work fine with 5.1.2 sdk.

Comment: no problems running your code on ipad or iphone, sdk 5.1.2. All console.log()s are shown. Do you have something else inside the views that is blocking the buttons?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried only with LiveView. Without LiveView works fine. Can you confirm the problem in LiveView ?

Comment: sorry, can't test that at the moment; don't have appc studio installed on my machine.

Comment: @Lorenzo: it was more about whether the arrays were correctly initialized in your code both times. (JS is a bit shaky...)

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Yes, already open https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20301

Answer (score 0):

It seems a memory lack. With sdk 5.1.2 I try the code in new project on iPad2 simulator without LiveView and it works fine but not in my real project. Now, in the new project, I have tried with 90 iterations and clicks works for first 18 buttons, in 5.1.1 works fine in all buttons.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor: 'white'});

var data = [];
var c =1;

for(var i=1; i<=90; i++){

    if (c == 1) {
        var page_view = Ti.UI.createView({
            layout: 'horizontal'
        });
    }

    var view = Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        width : 250,
        left: 5
    });



    var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        bottom : 10,
        left : 10,
        right : 10,
        height : 40,
        color : '#fff',
        backgroundColor : 'red',
        title : "click",
        ids: i
    });


    view.add(button);


    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('button: ' + e.source.ids);
    });

    page_view.add(view);

    if (c % 3 == 0) {
        data.push(page_view);
        c = 1;
    } else {
        c++;

        if (i == 90) {
            data.push(page_view);
        }
    }

}

var scroll_view = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    showPagingControl : true,
    top : 130,
    views: data,
    layout: 'horizontal'
});



win.add(scroll_view);
```

Comment: Could you try and set different values to cacheSize and see if that changes something (e.g. preload all pages). And its `memory leak` btw :)